How does powers behave with group homomorphism?
Consider the following problem: determine whether $f(x) = x^2$ forms a group homomorphism between the groups $\langle\mathbb{R},+\rangle$ and $\langle\mathbb{R},+\rangle$. Initially, I approached the problem as follows:
$$f(x+y) = (x+y)^2$$
$$f(x+y) = (x+y) + (x+y)$$
$$f(x+y) = x+y+x+y$$
$$f(x+y) = x+x+y+y$$
$$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$
Thus, it appeared to be a homomorphism. However, there exists another way to evaluate $(x+y)^2$ as $x^2 + 2xy + y^2$. If this interpretation holds, then $f(x)$ might not be a homomorphism anymore. The question arises: what exactly does the power symbol signify in this situation? Does it adhere to the conventional meaning, or is it defined by the repetition of the group's operation?

There is no "another" way, $(x+y)^2$ is always equal to $x^2+2xy+y^2$. This is almost never equal to $x^2+y^2$. So this is not a homomorphism.

When working with groups, isn't it the case that the power means the operation of the group is repetead? For example, with the group <G, +>, for any number a belonging to G, a to the power of n would mean a+a+a + . . . + a, n times. Could it be that I was mistaken?

@Davy133 Oh, it depends. When the group is additive, the notation you ask about will usually be consistent with the notation of the operation itself, so applying the group operation $n$ times on $x$ will here be denoted by $nx$, not by $x^n$. (unlike in multiplicative groups) The map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $x\to 2x$ is indeed a group homomorphism. But if in your question you meant the function $x\to x^2$ in the usual sense of squaring a real number (which I assume is the case) then this is not a homomorphism.

Have you tried very simple examples as possible counter-examples?

the $x^2$ in a general group operation means $x*x$, but in real numbers we conventionally write $x^2$  to represent multiplication of a real number with itself... so the function taking value x here gives $x^2$ means $f(x)=x.x$ and not $f(x)=x+x$

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.
